# MongoDB object property check if $exists with certain value in nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a DB collection like this.

```
  {
      "name" : "test",
      "gender" : "male",
      "attributes" : [ 
          {
              "field_id" : "123",
              "field_value" : "['Public']"
          }, 
          {
              "field_id" : "124",
              "field_value" : "true"
          },
          {
              "field_id" : "125",
              "field_value" : "['Single']"
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      "name" : "test2",
      "gender" : "male",
      "attributes" : [ 
          
          {
              "field_id" : "125",
              "field_value" : "['Married']"
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      "name" : "test3",
      "gender" : "male",
      "attributes" : [ 
          {
              "field_id" : "123",
              "field_value" : "['Public']"
          },
          {
              "field_id" : "125",
              "field_value" : "['Married']"
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      "name" : "test4",
      "gender" : "male",
      "attributes" : [ 
          {
              "field_id" : "123",
              "field_value" : "['Private']"
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      "name" : "test4",
      "gender" : "male",
      "attributes" : [ 
         
      ]
  }

]
```

I want to fetch all records which have `field_id` as `123` and `field_value` as `"Public"`; + records in which `field_id`
`123` doesn't exist under attributes.

I tried

```
var condition = { "attributes" :  {$elemMatch:{field_id:"123",field_value:{ $in:["Public"] }}}};

queryObj.push(condition);
```

this works fine to fetch records having  `field_id` as `123` and `field_value` as `Public`

But I also want to get records in which `field_id` as `123` doesn't exists, I tried this

```
var condition1 = 
{ "attributes" :  {$elemMatch:{field_id:"123",$exists:false}}}

queryObj.push(condition1);
```

but it returns an error as it's not right syntax.
Please guide how do I fetch as desired.

This is the expected output, As these records have only `Public` Value for `123` `field_id` or `field_id` as `123` DOES NOT EXIST in these.

```
[
  {
      "name" : "test",
      "gender" : "male",
      "attributes" : [ 
          {
              "field_id" : "123",
              "field_value" : "['Public']"
          }, 
          {
              "field_id" : "124",
              "field_value" : "true"
          },
          {
              "field_id" : "125",
              "field_value" : "['Single']"
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      "name" : "test3",
      "gender" : "male",
      "attributes" : [ 
          {
              "field_id" : "123",
              "field_value" : "['Public']"
          },
          {
              "field_id" : "125",
              "field_value" : "['Married']"
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      "name" : "test2",
      "gender" : "male",
      "attributes" : [ 
          
          {
              "field_id" : "125",
              "field_value" : "['Married']"
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      "name" : "test4",
      "gender" : "male",
      "attributes" : [ 
         
      ]
  }

]
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc I have updated the question and added expected output in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use two $elemMatch with $or operator.

your query should be something like this.

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          field_id: "123",
          field_value: "['Public']"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "$not": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            field_id: "123"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/CP3HSKmNpKM